# Enums : how to detect duplicate values

Tags: c++, enums

I would like to be able to detect enums duplicate values during compile time :

```
enum a{ A= 0, B =0 }; // A and B values are duplicate
```

I checked GCC options, without success.

The typical used case would be with some "legacy code" like :

```
enum b { A = /* some bitwise operators evaluated at compile time */,
         B = /* some bitwise operators evaluated at compile time */, ... }
```

Comment: Well this is a normal behavior... But maybe you can see what boost propose, I think they have some stuff to loop over an enum.

Comment: How is the enum generated?  Can you change the syntax?